# smoothing a resized image in Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, smoothing

I'm working my way through [How to Think Like a Computer Scientist](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/thinkcspy/toc.html#), and I've gotten stuck on the following exercise:

After you have scaled an image too much it looks blocky. One way of reducing the blockiness of the image is to replace each pixel with the average values of the pixels around it. This has the effect of smoothing out the changes in color. Write a function that takes an image as a parameter and smooths the image. Your function should return a new image that is the same as the old but smoothed.

The tutorial provides a truncated image module, but I am supposed to be able to solve this without using PIL. This is what I have so far:

```
import image
#image provided in tutorial
img = image.Image("luther.jpg")
win = image.ImageWin()
factor = 0

#resize the image
def resize(img, factor):
W = img.getWidth()
H = img.getHeight()

newW = int(W * factor)
newH = int(H * factor)

newImage = image.EmptyImage(newW, newH)

for col in range(newW):
    for row in range (newH):
        p = img.getPixel(col, row)
        newImage.setPixel(col * factor, row * factor, p)

newImage.draw(win)
img = newImage
return img
#smooth out the image   
def smooth(img):
    newImage = image.EmptyImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight())
    for col in range(img.getWidth()):
        for row in range(img.getHeight()):
            p1 = img.getPixel(col, row)
            p2 = img.getPixel(col+1, row)
            red1 = p1.getRed()
            red2 = p2.getRed()
            green1 = p1.getGreen()
            green2 = p2.getGreen()
            blue1 = p1.getBlue()
            blue2 = p2.getBlue()
            newRed = (red1 + red2)/2
            newGreen = (green1 + green2)/2
            newBlue = (blue1 + blue2)/2
            newPixel = image.Pixel(newRed, newGreen, newBlue)
            newImage.setPixel(col, row, newPixel)
    newImage.draw(win)
```

When I call the function, I get "Error: local variable red2 referenced before assignment." I have gone line-by-line with print statements; this error message is not returned until I try to create newPixel.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? I don't see how this function could have produced that error; perhaps it's coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post the full stack trace, as the activecode interpreter used in the tutorial does not provide it, just an error message. (I can't run the script in IDLE because I can't figure out how to install the image module used in the tutorial.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has mixed spaces and tabs. It's possible that the indentation levels aren't what you think they are, and the block structure of your program is messed up. Look at your program in an editor with 8-space tabs, ideally with an option to show whitespace characters, and see if your program looks like you thought it did. Also, stop mixing spaces and tabs. It'll mess you up again and again if you do.

Comment: Redid indentation using spaces exclusively, still receiving same error message.